# To make a responsive grid component based on screen size in an Ionic Framework

Tags: css, responsive-design, ionic-framework

I want to make a responsive grid component based on screen size in an Ionic mobile application page .

i have used the below code to achieve the grid system using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
</div>
```

But Is there any suggestion or guide to achieve this design in ionic framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two ways:

Download custom bootstrap build with Grid system and Responsive utilities.
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=11477931

A grid system based on the flex display property.
http://flexboxgrid.com/

Comment: The flex box grid system solved my problem .I designed already. Really thanks for your answer.